Viewer Node constantly changing position Blender 4.2
Does anyone know how to "deactivate" the adaptive repositioning of Viewer Node in Blender 4.2? Everytime I Ctrl-Shift-LMB on a node, the Viewer Node changes its position, which is very annoying.




This is one of the new features they added to Blender 4.2. It doesn't appear that there's any way to turn it off, unfortunately. https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/7be4d4f443a82a589ec47238765fc16aa9934246
